# XML contains strange characters with unknown encoding

Tags: xml, encoding, character-encoding

We are receiving an export of xml files from a third-party company.
While looking into these files, I noticed a few strange lines that look like the xml is corrupt at that part, making it impossible to import or validate that xml.

This image shows one of these "corrupt" parts.
[image]

Normally I'd just message the third-party company and ask them to fix whatever is wrong with those files, but I'm interested what could be the cause of such a "corruption".

A few things I noticed:

- The corruption repeats every 16280 characters.
- Its always the same "set" of characters per file, but they can slightly vary in other files.

The file(s) were downloaded via FTP. Multiple files contain slightly altered version of the corrupt part. However there are always 16280 chars between.

I've pretty much ruled out errors during transmit since I redownloaded the files multiple times.

Comment: What mode for ftp? Text or binary?

Comment: I think you need to follow the data flow backwards to find out at what point in the processing chain the corruption occurred. That may require the involvement of the data supplier.

Comment: @KevinBrown You are right, setting the ftp-mode to binary ( was on automatic before ) fixed to problem, but why?

Comment: Some old programs using old protocols have the notion that files should be "localized" when received from remote systems. But "binary" mode is the natural, non-interfering mode of file transfer. (Perhaps this program has a bug in non-binary mode, which would be more complex than binary mode.)